# Scroll UITableView to dismiss UIView Above

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIViewController` with following:

1. `UIView` as navigation (Button, Label, Button) Height: 60
2. `UIView` with Information (Labels) height: 110
3. `UITableView`

[image: screenshot]

I would like when the user scroll up, the 2nd `UIView` right above the `UITableVIew` to move with it and move off the screen, like this:

[image: screenshot2].

Finally, when user scroll down again, the `UIView` will appear again back to initial screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your 2nd information view from ViewController and set it as a header view of your tableView

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = informationView
```